# Newly created edge from boolean or cut operation left selected or marked. Function or feature?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, add-on, edit-mode, selection-tools

Is there anywhere a function, built in or not, that will mark (user defined) newly created edges, or leave the newly created edges highlighted for me to then mark or manipulate, if: The edge was made using a knife project cut, a slice operation in HOPs,  a bool tool cut, a carver operation, etc...? I see many ways this could be used. it seems like it should already be an operation option already and i feel like i'm missing something fundamentalobvious. Any insight or direction to point me in would be appreciated.

Comment: You could assign to a new vertex group (Ctrl G), you could mark as seam (U)...

Comment: Thank you for responding but its not what to do with the selection. Its how do have those selections made for me upon cut operation. Manually having to go back and select those new edges is what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: of course, you need to save or mark as soon as you've created the edge

Comment: Should i be expecting the edges say, of the knife cut or bool cut to be highlighted upon operation? i've been wondering if i'm crazy and thats the way it normally works and just isn't doing that for me now

Comment: If you cut with the knife for example, the new vertices are selected, you can either save as a vertex group or mark seam, but I've never heard of being able to select them automatically afterwards if you've not done that

Comment: Then my blender has stopped doing that for a while and i'll have to troubleshoot. Its been one of those things where i thought it was a thing and a thing i've used and didnt think about it. but now its gone or was i just remembering wrong? i asked around a few places and no one said Yes, it should already do what youre asking about. As far as doing things for me thats nbd. If the vertices are selected for me, thats the actual time saver. Marking or assigning or whatever would just be extra whatever

Comment: See: https://zupimages.net/up/23/37/5noh.gif

Comment: thank you for taking the time to show me. There's so many things this program does, it has been one of those things where i thought my memory was just faulty. i'm still curious about the other cut modes leaving vertices selected but until i get a simple knife cut to do it I don't know expected behavior. i'll troubleshoot. I'm glad i posted here. We can mark this mystery solved, case closed. thank you!

Comment: That said a boolean won't let the carved surface selected    ;)

Comment: okay. i was in face mode when i said that wasnt working. Still, this tells me i need to be more critical in my assumptions. I may have what i need and i'm just doing things rong

Comment: Marking for me is something i could prolly just build and a "nice to have". Its the selecting of the edges after a bool cut or HOPs slice cut that is valuable. For the bool cut to behave like the knife cut, with the edges selected after being applied. I'm using bool tool and after cut in vert or edge select mode they are not selected. Knife is doing it for me as it is for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you cut with the knife for example, the new vertices are selected, you can either save as a vertex group (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) or mark seam (<kbd>U</kbd>), but I've never heard of being able to select them automatically afterwards if you've not done that. But if you use a *Boolean* modifier for example, the carved part won't be selected.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the *Knife* tool, see the answer from @moonboots and for the *Boolean* modifier: well, before the modifier is applied there are of course no new vertices/edges selected because they are not yet created.

If you want to apply the modifier and mark the newly created vertices or edges as seams or put them inside a vertex group, there is no real automatic way of doing it, but a kind of workaround, you have to do two things before applying the modifier:

1. The object that you want to be cut needs to have **no vertices** selected in *Edit Mode*.
2. The cutting object needs to have **all vertices** selected in *Edit Mode*.

If you now apply the *Boolean* modifier and go into *Edit Mode* on the new object, all new vertices from the cutter are selected, while the original ones are not. Now you can either assign them to a vertex group with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or mark them as seams with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Mark Seam* or <kbd>U</kbd> > *Mark Seam*.

Comment: I knew the cutter's UV map and other properties are transferred, but I have no idea it even works for selection!